# bash variable inside quotes

Tags: bash, variables, scope, quotes, double-quotes

I want to run the following command

```
ssh data@server.org "cd /home/data/ ; chmod o+rx directory_$DATE"
```

$DATE is a bash variable. Is there a way to get it interpreted as a variable?

Comment: I assume you want the variable interpreted on the remote end, correct? As you have typed it, I believe the variable will be expanded on the local side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ssh data@server.org "cd /home/data/ ; chmod o+rx directory_\$DATE"
```